# What's the simplest solution/minimal HW I will need to buy to get this done?

Tags: networking, router, lan, vlan

The ISP only provides 1 WAN IP.

I will have the modem (in the apartment above me) in bridge mode. The modem is capable of VLAN but I don't think it is suitable for my situation.

Upstairs should have their own LAN, so I got them a router. There is no need to isolate their LAN from mine, but if it is easy to do so I will. There is absolute need to isolate my LAN (downstairs) from them.

Upstairs and downstairs are ethernet connected.

Downstairs I want to keep my Ubiquiti ER-LITE3 as a dual WAN router, running DHCP for my LAN. WAN1 should have the bridged address from the modem upstairs. WAN2 will be my own 4G modem (as a standby for WAN1 failing). The last and 3rd port feeds a standard consumer router for more ports and WiFi.

So I have 3 routers already: two consumer wifi routers, one Ubiquiti ER-LITE3 (3 ports only)

**Can I accomplish this purchasing one unmanaged switch or do I need a managed switch? I can place the switch upstairs or downstairs. The ER-LITE3 can do VLANs, but it must be downstairs.**

PS: No double NAT anywhere (that'd be easy and asking for trouble)

Comment: The answer would largely depend on your ISP... Will they hand out more than one DHCP address? Many ISP will only allow one public DHCP address per access device (modem, ONT, etc)... If they will allow more than one, just put a small dumb switch in place at the modem, connect the modem, upstairs router, and downstairs router and your done... If they do not, then your just daisy chaining off the upstairs LAN anyway so it doesn't matter if you add a switch or not. Of course, this isn't the IDEAL way to handle this. Better would be a router than is capable of multiple LANs and replace all routers.

Comment: I only get one WAN IP from the ISP, @acejavelin. Thanks, should have disclosed this from the start.

Comment: Looks like I might have to put the ER3 upstairs to handle the VLAN. problem is getting the WAN2 (4g) antenna there.

Comment: updated the Q, the modem is capable of VLAN but I can't double NAT and I need the ERLITE for the dual WAN.